# What design differences make ram faster than ssd for read/write

Tags: memory, ram, dram, ssd

I understand that RAM is connected directly to the CPU via a high bandwidth bus, and SSD is a peripheral, but my assumption is that there are also electrical design differences (e.g. memory cell design and layout) that make RAM faster than SSD for reads/writes. If that is true, and with bus bandwidth & latency differences aside, what are those design differences, and how do they affect speed?

Comment: The architectural differences are enormous. https://www.cactus-tech.com/resources/blog/details/solid-state-drive-primer-7-controller-architecture-basic-overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest difference is that SSDs are based on NAND flash cells with the serial structure shown below.

[image: NAND flash structure]

Where DRAM accesses all of the bits in a row at the same time, NAND flash serially accesses the row.  This significantly slows down read access versus DRAM.

Write access is significantly slowed because flash uses a floating gate which requires orders of magnitude more programming time than the capacitor in a DRAM cell. In most cases, since the write can only set a bit to 0 and erasing is required to set a bit to 1, writes also require erasing before programming.  DRAM writes can set either state with no speed penalty.

Answer (score 2):

Their physical structure is totally different. DRAM cells are based on a capacitor holding its voltage.

Flash is based on a floating gate design, where the physical properties of the cell changes with a write.

Comment: How does this affect r/w speeds?

Comment: This is more than *too broad*.

Comment: I'm wondering why a capacitive memory cell (DRAM) is faster than a floating gate cell.

Comment: is it because capacitor can quickly charge and discharge compared to whatever the other one was(floating what?)?